# string split based on char \

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

Got a bit of a mind freeze at the moment.
I have the following syntax:-

```
        string[] repname = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.ToString().Split('\');
```

and I get an error on the split character. Can anyone advise on how I can do the split using the \ character as the delimiter?

Cheers

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use

```
Split('\\')
```

"\" is an [escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character).

Answer (score 1):

\ is an excape character in C#.

You need to do one of the following:

```
Split('\\');
```

or

```
Split(@'\');
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the `\` character is meant to escape other characters. If you wish it to be taken *literally*, you need to escape it with another `\`. So, in order to escape on backslashes, you'll provide `\\`.

Answer (score 1):

Split takes a char[] as a parameter, not a char. Try;

```
string[] repname = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.ToString().Split(new char[] {'\\'});
```

Comment: Why the downvote? The non-escaped character is only part of the story, there is no overload of String.Split that takes a single char.

Answer (score 0):

```
 string[] repname = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.ToString().Split(new string[]{"\\"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```